# Creating a swiping card stack with UICollectionView and UICollectionViewCells?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

So far, I made my collection views which scroll horizontally in either left or right.I added UICollectionViewCells into one UICollectionView. My problem that I'm having is trying to find the right settings to make the cards stack on top of the first card, as demonstrated in the photo below.

[image]

Here are the settings for my collectionView and how it displays its cells.

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
   let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 78
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return cv

}()
```

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/PushpaCollectionViewLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to subclass `UICollectionViewLayout`, set the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` for each cell, and make sure to set `zIndex` to the `indexPath.row` of the item in order to get overlapping. You can take a look at my sample project on [GitHub](https://github.com/mpdifran/OverlapCollectionView/blob/master/CollectionViewCustomInsertion/OverlapCollectionViewLayout.swift) that implements something very similar.

There are some bugs in `UICollectionViewLayout` related to animating insertions of new cells when the cells are overlapping (which is why I made the sample project in the first place).

Comment: Great, Mark! This was sort of what I was looking for. Do you know of any specifics on animating each card to stack similarly to the iPhone's multitasking?

Comment: Do you mean animating it while the user scrolls? You can achieve the effect by modifying the transform3D property of the attributes based on the content offset of the collection view, and the location of the item.