# How to implement horizontal stacked cards which moves from left to right when we swipe?

Tags: ios, swift, horizontal-scrolling, stacked

I want to show horizontal stacked cards , which moves one by one from left to right by swipe action . Once a card moves it forms a stack on the right side

I have tried seeing various libraries which straight away does not implement this. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/iaccordion this one came close it has vertical swipe and is in objective C. Can you point me in the right direction to get this done ?

Comment: Try using `UICollectionView`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a swiping card stack with UICollectionView and UICollectionViewCells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084777/creating-a-swiping-card-stack-with-uicollectionview-and-uicollectionviewcells)

Answer (score 0):

Card-like stacks are very easy to make but can be hard to perfect when it comes to some effects. Basically each of your views has one of 3 possible positions; on initial stack, on target stack, user is dragging it.

So the simplest implementation is to define 2 centers for your views and have 2 arrays of views. At the beginning all the views are in the first array. All views in first array should be centered to first center and in second array centered to the second center. Now you need a pan gesture. When a gesture starts you should check if it starts on the left stack if it does simply remove it from first array and begin changing its center. Like

```
func onPanGesture(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .began:
        if leftStackView.bounds.contains(sender.location(in: leftStackView)), viewsInLeftStack.count > 0 {
            pannedView = viewsInLeftStack.removeLast()
        }
    case .changed:
        pannedView?.center = sender.location(in: self.view)
    }
}
```

Now when finger is lifted you should check if card should be put back or moved to the other stack. So another case for gesture recognizer must be added:

```
    case .ended, .cancelled:
        if let pannedView = pannedView {
            if(abs(pannedView.center.x-leftStackView.center.x) > abs(pannedView.center.x-rightStackView.center.x)) {
                // Closer to the right one horizontally
                viewsInLeftStack.append(pannedView)
                pannedView.center = leftStackView.center
            } else {
                // Closer to the left one horizontally
                viewsInRightStack.append(pannedView)
                pannedView.center = rightStackView.center
            }
        }
```

In basics that is all you need. But then comes making the component nice. For instance when card is released it should animate to its deck:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    pannedView.center = self.rightStackView.center
}
```

Then cards may be a bit displaced on both of decks which is easiest to apply some transform. They may even rotate a bit as you drag them... But this is all up to you what you want to implement.